# How to run Karma+Jasmine+angular tests using Visual studio 2015?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Is it possible to run Karma+Jasmine+angular tests using Visual studio 2015? I tried very hard in past few days to do this but I am not able to achieve this. My existing project is created using webstorm and works like charm in webstorm. I am amaze the ease with which Webstorm can run karma test. Unfortunately, I only have 30 days license for Webstorm and will need to be able to run tests using Visual Studio 2015 going forward.

I have tried:

Karma Test Adapter

Jasmine Test Adapter

Chutzpah Test Runner

but the lack of documentation and instructional videos on these are big hurdles.

Comment: can you provide more details on what you tried for Karma Test Adapter?

Comment: @sparticus_37 are you asking the questioner or answerer?

Comment: Apologies, that was intended for you @user2619299

Answer (score 0):

Karma Test adapter worked for me.  Try downloading it through [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4cd59e4a-82e8-4b4e-8302-d102fc81b090)

You may also need to download Karma through the Command Line.

Comment: @Archemede What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @user2619299 I am using Visual Studio 2015, I have not yet downloaded "Update 2"

Comment: @Archemede the link is last updated on 4/3/2015. Is that still being maintain? I had existing angular application which I was able to work in Visual Studio except the tests. Webstorm seems to be designed for this. Our licenses for Webstorm just got approved so I might not look into this much. Thanks for taking time to reply this thread.

Comment: @user2619299  no problem at all!